# What exactly causes "licensedContent" to return true

Tags: youtube-api

I'm trying to figure out exactly what causes the "licensedContent" flag from the "contentDetails" info of a video listing to be set to true.

It seems to be any video uploaded to a channel that has content tracking on.

Basically my end goal here is to be able to discern whether or not a YouTube video has been claimed by a content owner / license issuer to detect both re-hosted content, and content that is "Licensed" by third party companies like Jukin Media or similar.

I'd also like to get the "Suggested by 'Jukin Media' : url of other video" part from an API call, but that doesn't seem to be exposed anywhere that I've seen.

Answer (score 0):

contentDetails.licensedContent - Indicates whether the video represents licensed content, which means that the content was uploaded to a channel linked to a YouTube content partner and then claimed by that partner.

https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos#contentDetails.licensedContent

Comment: Right, that's what the API doc says, but the person I tested with uploaded a video to their channel as "unlisted", didn't "claim" it, and it the API still returns that it's Licensed. When it was uploaded to a different channel without tracking, it no longer said it was licensed.